# Is there any way to write JSON array list in application.properties file (spring-boot)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

Is there any way to write Json array list in application.properties file (spring-boot), so that I can read whole Json with minimum code?

Below is my json object.

```
{ "userdetail": [
    {
      "user": "user1",
      "password": "password2",
      "email": "email1"
    },
    {
      "user": "user2",
      "password": "password2",
      "email": "email2"
    }]}
```

And also if I use jasypt to encode password, then what the code will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [Spring Boot Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml)

You can use YAML

```
my:
   servers:
       - dev.example.com
       - another.example.com
```

or normal configuration property arrays:

```
my.servers[0]=dev.example.com
my.servers[1]=another.example.com
```

Than you can load these properties into application this way:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class Config {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```

For your case I would try something like:

```
users.userdetail[0].user=..
users.userdetail[0].password=..
...
```

And read it via

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="users")
public class Userdetail {

    private class User {
         public String user;
         public String password;
         public String email;
    }  

    private List<User> userdetails = new ArrayList<User>();

    public List<User> getUserdetails() {
        return this.userdetails;
    }
}
```